# forecast with data from a matrix in r

Tags: r

I want to produce a forecast of a matrix.. 
for e.g

```
> x<-ts(...,start=c(2009,1),frequency=12)
```

so.

```
       A       B        .    .  .        G
  2009/1    2314     1456             3021
  2009/2    2345     2351             2241  
       .       .        .                .
       .       .        .                .
       .       .        .                .
 2014/12    3210     3412             3199
```

to get the first column `x[,1]` the second `x[,2]`..
now i want to forecast all the products (A,B,C,....,G) with one order.
the forecast  method is holtswinter.
so i guess it would be something like that:

```
for(i in 1:7)
fit1[i]<-hw(x[,i],h=12,model="additive")
fit2[i]<-hw(x[,i],h=12,model="multiplicative")
```

Comment: Elaborate what are you doing and what is problem?

Comment: i want with one order (i think something like a loop) to forecast the above matrix for each column separate..but i don't know how to do it.

Comment: You can iterate a procedure over the columns of a matrix using `?apply`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is probably to use `predict()` together with `HoltWinters()` from stats, much like the other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29791443/how-can-i-make-a-loop-in-r-of-a-matrix/29792074#29792074) you asked:

```
dat <- data.frame( a =rnorm(100), b=rnorm(100), c=rnorm(100))
myTs <- ts(dat, start=2000, frequency=12)
sapply(colnames(myTs), function(i,...) predict(HoltWinters(myTs[,i],...)),  seasonal = "additive" )
          a           b           c 
-0.49806413 -0.35461294  0.02780248
```

or output as a `list`:

```
lapply(myTs, function(x,...) predict(HoltWinters(x,...)), seasonal = "additive")
$a
            May
2008 -0.4980641

$b
            May
2008 -0.3546129

$c
            May
2008 0.02780248
```