# How can i make a loop in R of a matrix

Tags: r

I have a matrix(named x) of "n" columns and "k" rows..I want to make a loop but i don't know how.

```
fit1=hw(x[,1],h=12)
fit2=hw(x[,2],h=12)
fit3=hw(x[,3],h=12)
fit4=hw(x[,4],h=12)
fit5=hw(x[,5],h=12)
.

.
.
fitn=hw(x[,n],h=12)
```

The problem is that if i don't make a loop for that, i will not be able to continue. To be more specific, i am in a project that i have to forecast the data of a matrix. Through some test i concluded that the best method for my data is the HoltsWinter. If a had only one column this would be easy.

```
x<-read.table()
xx<-ts(x,start=,frequency=)
fit<-hw(xx,h=12,model="additive") or fit<-hw(xx,h=12,model="multiplicative")
fit$mean
and in final step a plot.
```

But in my circumstance i don't have one column..but i have lots of them..so it is not possible to do the same think n-times. I believe that exist a loop that can help me solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
fit=list()
for (i in 1:ncol(x)) {

fit[[i]]=hw(x[,i],h=12)

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should probably look into the `apply` family. Some examples:
`lapply()` used to calculate the mean for each series (columns):

```
x <- data.frame( a =rnorm(100), b=rnorm(100), c=rnorm(100))
xx <- ts(x, start=2000, frequency=4)
lapply(x, mean)
$a
[1] 0.03697344

$b
[1] -0.1540831

$c
[1] -0.2267992
```

Or `sapply` used here together with `HoltWinters()` from `stats`:

```
sapply(names(x), function(i,...) HoltWinters(xx[,i],...),  seasonal = "additive" )
             a           b           c          
fitted       Numeric,384 Numeric,384 Numeric,384
x            Numeric,100 Numeric,100 Numeric,100
alpha        0.1388421   0.1657252   0.06299144 
beta         0.08518182  0.1902871   0.2389817  
gamma        0.1799012   0.2454659   0.1603644  
coefficients Numeric,6   Numeric,6   Numeric,6  
seasonal     "additive"  "additive"  "additive" 
SSE          112.2228    137.912     135.6189   
call         Expression  Expression  Expression
```